# Program crashes when using modules partitions and implementation units

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I have following program:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

import animal;

int main() {
 auto s = makeSound();
 printf("%s", s.c_str());
 return 0;
}
```

and module interface:

```cpp
module;
#include <string>
export module animal;
import :sound;

export std::string makeSound() {
 return makeSound_Impl();
}
```

and module implementation unit:

```cpp
module;

#include <string>

module animal:sound;

std::string makeSound_Impl() {
 return "Wroooarrh";
}
```

Program is compiled with:

```
g++ -fmodules-ts -g -std=c++20 animal_sound.cpp -c -o animal_sound.o
g++ -fmodules-ts -g -std=c++20 animal.cpp -c -o animal.o
g++ -fmodules-ts -g -std=c++20 animal.o animal_sound.o main.cpp -o main.exe
```

Compiler version:

```
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~22.04) 13.1
```

Program crashes on basic_string:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555566c2 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_data (this=0xd00aa32b9e55bf00) at /usr/include/c++/13/bits/basic_string.h:223
223           { return _M_dataplus._M_p; }
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00005555555566c2 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_data (this=0x0) at /usr/include/c++/13/bits/basic_string.h:223
#1  0x0000555555556f3a in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::c_str (this=0x7fffffffda50) at /usr/include/c++/13/bits/basic_string.h:2584
#2  0x0000555555556ea6 in main () at main.cpp:7
```

When compiled with module 'animal' defining `makeSound` directly (not working as proxy to implementation unit):

```cpp
module;
#include <string>
export module animal;

export std::string makeSound() {
 return "Sound!";
}
```

Everything works fine (program does not crash). Am I doing something wrong, or that's a compiler issue?

**EDIT**

Interestingly I was able to reproduce the issue without implementation units. If no include `<string>` is present in module 'animal' then problem is gone.

```
module;
#include <string>
export module animal:sound;

export std::string makeSound() {
 return "Wroooarrh";
}
```

```cpp
module;
// #include <string>  // Adding include makes program crash
export module animal;
export import :sound;
```

**EDI2**

Reported bug on GCC Bugzilla: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=111447

Comment: Seems like a compiler bug. It would be wise inspecting the generated assembly and sending that to the GCC team

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Just send them the source code, surely (and a note of the compiler version in use).

Comment: I tried running this with MSVC. At first it did not work. When I made a change to the module implementation file, it did. All I did was add the keyword `export`.  Try using `export module animal:sound;`.

Comment: @tbxfreeware but that would man shift from module implementation unit to module interface unit...

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work? The Microsoft documentation calls it a _partition interface unit._ I am still new to modules, so I am still at the "lets-get-it-working" stage. I have been using this idiom quite a lot, even for names that are not exported from the _primary module interface unit_.

Comment: Here is a bit more information from the Microsoft documentation: _A partition has an interface file, and zero or more implementation files._ See: [Module partition files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-named-modules-cpp?view=msvc-170#module-partition-files). Interestingly, I have not yet located a similar statement on CppReference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you seem to be having is due to each of the module units in the same module having a `#include <string>` in them. This *should not* be a problem; there should be nothing wrong with different module units in the same module including the same header in their global module fragments. But your compiler won't seem to let you do it.

That makes it a compiler bug.

Answer (score 0):

###### Two ways to make this work

I found two ways to make this work.

1. Change module `animal:sound` from an implementation unit into an interface unit.
2. Eliminate module partition `animal:sound`, and add an implementation unit for module `animal`.

These solutions were tests using MSVC.

###### Method 1

This was the simpler of the two methods.

I merely added the keyword `export` to the module declaration for module `animal:sound`.

```cpp
// animal-sound.ixx
module;

#include <string>

export module animal:sound;  // add the keyword `export`

std::string makeSound_Impl() {
    return "Wroooarrh";
}
```

Nothing else was changed, and the program ran fine.

I am still unsure what to make of Microsoft's explanation that, "A partition has an interface file, and zero or more implementation files." (See [Module partition files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-named-modules-cpp?view=msvc-170#module-partition-files).)

If true, that would explain the problems cited in the OP. The program there has an implementation unit for the partition `animal:sound`, but no accompanying interface unit.

In a cursory reading of the [material at CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules), and an even quicker scan of "Section 10.1 Module units and purviews" in the C++ Standard, I could not confirm the Microsoft statement.

###### Method 2

Another way to make this work is to create a *module implementation unit* for module `animal` directly.

This method eliminates the module partition `animal:sounds`.

The main routine is identical to that in the original question.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <cstdio>

import animal;

int main() {
    auto s = makeSound();
    printf("%s", s.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Next comes the *module interface unit* for module `animal`.

```cpp
// animal.ixx
// Module Interface Unit
// (For gcc, this may be named "animal.cpp".)
module;
#include <string>
export module animal;

// Declared, but not exported.
std::string makeSound_Impl();

export std::string makeSound() {
    return makeSound_Impl();
}
```

One of the advantages to using `.ixx` for interface units is that `.cpp` is available for implementation units. Hence the name `animal.cpp` below.

```cpp
// animal.cpp
// Module Implementation Unit
// (For gcc, this might be named "animal-impl.cpp".)
module;
#include <string>

module animal;
std::string makeSound_Impl() {
    return "Wroooarrh";
}
```

The output is as expected:

```
Wroooarrh
```

Comment: Thank you for the reposne, but I know how to make it work. The questions about if the construct is correct, according the standard and it's compiler issue. Or it is against the rules... https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf - see example on page 240. `Internals` - is module implementation unit and partition. No corresponding module interface units is present for `Internals`